# Touchscreen using excel on tv screen VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make an excel sheet that when you click on a cell it changes EX: click once it changes from IN to OUT click again changes to LUNCH click again changes to PTO next time back to IN.   I got it to work for one cell M10 in example below but i have 22 different cells i need this to work the same way on the sheet. How can i make this work for multiple cells.  The cells are D3,G3,J3,M3,P3,D6,G6,J6,M6,P6,D10,G10,J10,M10,P10,D14,G14,J14,M14,P14,D18,and G18

Any help is greatly appreciated

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
'Manager Clockin Sheet
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  With Target
  If .Address = Range("M10").Address Then
    Select Case .Value
      Case "IN"
        .Value = "Out"
      Case "Out"
        .Value = "Lunch"
      Case "Lunch"
        .Value = "PTO"
      Case "PTO"
        .Value = "IN"
      Case "IN"
      Case Else
        .Value = "Out"
    End Select
  End If
  End With
  Range("M11").Select
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Application.Intersect` here

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub 'single cell selections only
    'in range of interest?
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, _
       Me.Range("D3,G3,J3,M3,P3,D6,G6,J6,M6,P6,D10,G10,J10,M10,P10,D14,G14,J14,M14,P14,D18,G18"))
  
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.Value = NextValue(rng.Value)
    Range("M11").Select 'rng.Offset(1, 0).Select 
  
End Sub

Function NextValue(v)
    Select Case UCase(v)
        Case "IN": NextValue = "Out"
        Case "OUT": NextValue = "Lunch"
        Case "LUNCH": NextValue = "PTO"
        Case "PTO": NextValue = "In"
        Case Else: NextValue = "Out"
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I think the `Range("M11").Select` is meant to be dynamic like `Target.Offset(1, 0).Select`

Comment: @Toddleson - added that as an option.  Thanks